# Perform An Action When Proceeding To Payment in prestashop.

Tags: prestashop, payment

After selecting any payment method on order page. I want to run a small php code so is there any way to perform an action after chosen any payment method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a module and use a hookActionPayamentConfirmation

```
public function hookActionPaymentConfirmation()
{
    /* Place your code here. */
}
```

if you do not want to display anything

```
public function hookActionValidateOrder()
{
    /* Place your code here. */
}
```

if you want display a element

```
public function hookDisplayShoppingCart()
{
    /* Place your code here. */
}
```

Comment: This hook is called from back office when a payment is confirmed by admin